# req.session.userId returns undefined in post request

Tags: node.js, express, session

I have the line `req.session.userId = user._id;` in a post request with route `/signin`. When I put `console.log(req.session.userId)` after that line, it does return the user id. But req.session.userId returns undefined in a post request with route `/notes`. How can I get the user id?

session in MongoDB Compass indeed contains the userId:

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"userId":"5b1634522951cc240c2fe55f"}
```

client post request /notes

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newNote)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    newNote._id = data._id;
    const storedNotes = this.state.notes;
    storedNotes.unshift(newNote);
    this.setState({notes: storedNotes});
})
.catch(error => {
    this.setState({error: 'Error adding note.'});
    console.error('Error during adding note', error);
})
```

server post request /notes

```
app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    if(!req.body.content) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Note content can not be empty"
        });
    }

    console.log(req.session.userId);

    const note = new Note({
        title: req.body.title || "Untitled Note", 
        content: req.body.content,
    });

    note.save()
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Note."
        });
    });
};
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/trial')
.then(() => {
  console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...');
  process.exit();
});
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'work hard',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: db
    })
  }));

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") 
        res.sendStatus(200);
  else 
        next();
});

require('./routes/userRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/quoteRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/noteRoutes')(app);

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Express app listening on port 8000');
});
```

Comment: can you show the post code (client). I guess you don't include the "credentials" (cookies).

Comment: I tried adding credentials: 'include' to the client post request. Still returns undefined. How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MDN page for fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server,
>   resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on
>   maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init
>   option must be set).

And, without cookies, your server won't have access to session data.

The credentials option for `fetch()` can have three main values: `omit`, `same-origin`, or `include`.  You will want to set one of the last two values like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',     // make sure session cookies are included
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newNote)
})
```

You will need the `credentials` setting for ALL `fetch()` requests that you want cookies sent with, whether they are GET or POST or any other verb.

Comment: I added this line with same-origin or include, but it still doesn't work. What else can I do?

Comment: @lmathl - What is the URL of the web page (in the browser URL bar) that you're doing this `fetch()` from?

Comment: @lmathl - So, the server you show the code for is your port 8000 server that is a different server than the port 3000 server that loaded the web page?  Why do you think the port 8000 server has the same session as the port 3000 server?  Did you specifically code the two servers to share sessions?

Comment: I used app.use(session(...)) in my server. When I log in, the userId is created. So there has to be a session.

Comment: @lmathl - Can I confirm that you're using two separate node.js servers on the same host, one is on port 3000 that the web page comes from and the other is on port 8000 that you're trying to use `fetch()` to reach?  Why are you using two separate node.js servers?  When you log in and create your logged in session, which server are you doing that on?

Comment: I used react to create the view in port 3000. Express server for CRUD in port 8000. The above client post request is made in 3000 to 8000.

Comment: So it would be a better idea to do both in just one port?

Comment: @lmathl - That's one host, but TWO servers, one running on port 3000 and one running on port 8000.  I would presume that you aren't doing something properly in the code of your two servers so that they can share sessions between them.  The `credentials: 'include'` will allow them to share cookies, but you may have to do more with your session stuff to make sure they share actual sessions.

Comment: When I log in, the session should be on 8000.

Comment: @lmathl - One server only would make this problem go away (you would still need the `credentials: 'include'` in the `fetch()`), but all requests would easily see the same session object.  With proper coding, you can achieve two separate server processes sharing the same session objects, but it requires careful and explicit coding to achieve that.

Comment: @lmathl - Is your question answered now?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, please tell us what has not yet been answered.

Comment: I made an edit request on your answer to add the line 'Do the same on the signin post request.' but it's not accepted. I thought I just need to add credentials: 'include' for requests that involve the note database, but really the signin post request also needs that line. If you edit your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @lmathl - You need `credentials: 'include'` for ***all*** `fetch()` requests that you want cookies sent with.  That's what my answer explains.  This has nothing to do with GET or POST.  Any ajax request that you want cookies sent with.  You are the one who knows which requests you need cookies sent with (not me) so use it where needed.